# No route matches {:controller=>"devise/dokumente"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to add Devise to my Rails app. But somehow i have problems with my routes, i get:

```
 No route matches {:controller=>"devise/dokumente"}
```

In line 21:

```
  <li><%= link_to 'Dokumente', controller: 'dokumente', action: 'index' %></li>
```

I tried several things like:

```
  dokumente_path
```

But then i get the error:

```
  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"dokumente"}
```

Because i have only the action/view index.

What should i change in my routes so that dokumente_path goes to dokumente index?

My routes:

```
 resources :dokumente do
  collection do
   get :set_image
  end
 end  

   get "dokumente/index"
   post "dokumente/index"
```

Comment: I tried it before! undefined local variable or method `dokumentes_path'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Dokumente', dokumente_index %></li>
```

Or, if you want `dokumente_path` , add this to your routes:

```
  get "dokumente/index", :as => 'dokumente_path'
  post "dokumente/index", :as => 'dokumente_path'
```

Comment: I had the same problem anywhere I had 'controller=>foo' in a link_to helper. I changed them to foo_index_path to fix the problem.